# How to access a non-FXML attribute inside an EventHandler?

Tags: java, javafx, event-handling, eventhandler

Suppose we have the following constructor of a simple JavaFX project:

```
    public class FXMLController{
        private Model model;
        @FXML private Button button;

        public void initializer(){
            button.setOnMouseClicked(new EventHandler<MouseEvent>(){
                @Override public void handle(MouseEvent e){
                    this.model.setSomeVariable();//The variable model is not visible
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

As commented in the code the variable model is not visible from the EventHandler and shows the following error:

```
model cannot be resolved or is not a field
```

I know that this can be solved by defining an onAction method inside the FXML and implementing it outside the initializer method. I wonder if this is the only solution to this problem or if there is another way of doing it.

Comment: It's the "this", which in that context means the EventHandler that you're defining.  Just take out the "this" and it will work.

Comment: Better yet, use a lambda expression, then you can keep the "this" if you really want it:  button.setOnMouseClicked(e -> this.model.setSomeVariable());

Comment: Thanks, it worked removing the "this".